# After pushState use the asp runat="server" controls

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am using masterpages in my site to change the url in the site. I use the `<a>` of my navigation bar using a full change/reload of the url in the `href` to webforms nested within my masterpage.

After doing some ajax on the site with `UpdatePanels`, I couldn't stop to try something with the `pushState`.

I did some research on the internet, and while doing this:

```
$("a[data-role='ajax']").click(function (e) {
    if (Modernizr.history) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var pageName = $(this).attr("href");
                    window.history.pushState(null, "", pageName);
                    navigateToPage();
    }
});
```

I really get a change of the url and with some more code implemented where was the masterpage content page, I put a `div` where I dynamically load it with a new content from other page. As a simple approach I have:

**Home.aspx**

```
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
 <h1>Home</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.aspx" data-role="ajax">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page1.aspx" data-role=
"ajax">Page 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content-host" class="fragment">
    Home
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Page1.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Home</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.aspx" data-role="ajax">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page1.aspx" data-role=
"ajax">Page 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="content-host" class="fragment">
    page 1
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
     <script src="modernizr-custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Clicking the `a` the scripts changes the url with the `pushState` and the new information on the `div` "contest-host" is changed.

Basicaly when navigate to **page1.aspx** the url changes to **page1.aspx** and in the div it shows the textbox, but my problem is when I click on the textbox and put some text and do the enter it comes back to the **home.aspx**. I noticed if I go to **page1.aspx** and press enter in the url the page reloads and the textbox on postback doesn't make the page go back to **home.aspx**.

I'm not an expert in ASP. This is the kind of situation that I think that there is no way to keep the next page and do something like a `textchangedevent` without a full reload, but anyway I ask, if it is possible.

Comment: Mixing classic Web Forms with client-side history is likely difficult or impossible.  You should use ASP.Net MVC with a client-side MVC framework like React or Vue.js.

Comment: I don't think ASP.net is going to let you change a page to post to another page because of viewstate, but you could try changing `#form1`'s `action` to the new url... it's worth a shot, although I have very l little confidence that it will work as you expect.  I would look into using javascript/ajax for your form post rather than posting back using the form.